# Most elegant solution to changing structuremap context

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

with structuremap we're doing:

```
    internal static class ContainerBootstrapper
        {
    public static void BootstrapStructureMap()
        {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<SafeFlowContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use<SafeFlowContext>();
            x.For<DbContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use<SafeFlowContext>();

            x.For<IInterface>().HttpContextScoped().Use<Class>();
            ...
```

Only once per application, as per:

```
    public sealed class ServiceLoc
        {
            public static ServiceLoc GetInstance()
            {
                return new ServiceLoc();
            }

            private IInterfacesHere

            private ServiceLocator()
            {
                if (!_isInitialized)
                {
                    lock (_lockThis)
                    {
                        ContainerBootstrapper.BootstrapStructureMap();
                        ...
```

I'm writing unit tests, and I know I can change the scope from HttpContextScoped to Hybrid as this is the cause of my issue.

However being a bit of a purist, I don't want to change production code for testing purposes and I don't want to copy paste code blocks (or entire class files) to change the scope.

I do not mind however potentially changing the scope based on a conditional (if it's succinct).

So far I've been thinking of attempting to spoof my unit tests to mark them as HttpContext scoped and adding a bool switch to the service locator, perhaps with a default argument, such that when my unit test calls it via:

```
_serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.GetInstance(bool httpcontext=false);
```

For example, but this just doesn't seem satisying. I've checked the structuremap site but the examples I saw don't seem to fit my purpose.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried conditional compilation constants?

Comment: @AdrianStanculescu No sir - could you clarify in this instance please?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it involved changing production code, I ended up simply changing the scoping method to use 'HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped' as it was plainly superior.